# PHP generates spaces before the XML starts

Tags: php, xml

I have this problem: I want to generate an xml page from PHP script. The user that want the document can connect to a specific URL with specific parameters. But something not work because I think there are some whitespace chracters between the start of the document and the start of xml declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

I removed in the code all the characters between `<?php` and `header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');` and now look like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');

//ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
//error_reporting(E_ALL);

include("some_file.php");
require_once("some_file.php");

// some php code

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<response></response>");

// other php code

echo $xml->asXML();
?>
```

When I run this script, Firefox gives me this message:

```
XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
Line Number 1
```

Why does I have this error?

Comment: Try to remove spaces **before** `<?php`, not after.

Comment: Also check your `include`d files for whitespace

Comment: Remove `?>` from the end of the PHP files. Sometimes there are spaces or newlines after it that break the things.

Comment: Taking a guess here that your files are saved as *UTF-8 with BOM*. Otherwise, inspect the XML file with a hex editor to see what it is.

Comment: I try to remove byte-order marks with HexEdit editor but I don't found nothing that help me

Comment: Just *look* at the file in a hex editor and show us what the first characters in the file are.

Comment: start with `3C` that is the character '<'